# Extending an operator from simple functions to $L^2$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\phi$ be a simple function on [-1,1]. Then we define
$$T\phi(x) = \int_{-1}^1 \frac{2^{x-y}}{|x|+|y|}\phi(y)\,dy$$
I want to show that we can extend $T$ to an operator that maps $L^2([-1,1])$ to itself.

I am pretty rusty when it comes to this, but here's what I've thought of so far. Let $f\in L^2([-1,1])$, and let $\phi_n$ be a sequence of simple functions that go to $f$ (the simple functions are dense in $L^2$ so we can do this).

Then define $Tf(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} T\phi_n(x)$. Now we need to show that the limit exists, and that the limit is in $L^2([-1,1])$. Is there anything else I need to show?

Here is where I am even less sure of myself. I think the question is vague, because it doesn't say anything about proving that it's a unique extension, or even continuous, although those seem like reasonable things. If I did want to show that it's unique and continuous, then I think I need to show that if $\phi_n$ and $\psi_n$ are sequences of simple functions that both converge to $f$, then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} T\phi_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} T\psi_n$$

That's really as far as I've gotten. Basically just figuring out a strategy for the question. Do I have the right idea, or is my strategy off? I've tried going further, but I haven't gotten anywhere.

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just use the same formula to define $T$ on all of $L^2([-1,1])$? If $V$ and $W$ are Banach spaces and $T:V'\rightarrow W$ is a linear map from some dense subspace $V'\subseteq V$, if you can show that $\|Tv\|\leq C\|v\|$ for $v\in V'$ and some constant $C$ then $T$ extends uniquely.

Comment: yes, you need to show that $T $ is bounded for the $L^2$ norm on your "simple functions", assuming those are a dense subset of $L^2([-1,1])$, you get that $T$ extends to a bounded operator on $L^2([-1,1])$

Comment: Ok sounds good. I will try showing that's it's a bounded linear operator. I think the linear part is trivial, but the bounded part is not. If anyone has any ideas, feel free to share! I tried showing it's bounded earlier, but no success, but maybe that is the right approach.